# I want to ask about elasticsearch and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

When I setup Elasticsearch on Ubuntu, I made a mistake when putting 7.11.2 to:
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.11.2/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.11.2.list

so now, when running sudo apt-get update, there is a error:

Err:6 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.11.2/apt stable Release
404  Not Found [IP: xxxx]

How do I modify it in /etc/apt/sources.list?
Any help welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove that elastic apt file by.don't be afraid,apt source list just some address point to software repository.just make sure you don't delete wrong file.

```sh
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.11.2.list
```

If you want install elasticsearch.you can get doc from here.https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

```
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
```

Comment: I installed elasticsearch: sudo apt-get install elasticsearch after running the wrong command. Now, I have used sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.11.2.list. Does it affect my elasticsearch at all?

Comment: due to they are all major version 7,so only some bug fixes changed.this will not cause any problem.I took at ease while update small version in my production environment.